# Javascript conditional statement not executing

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to make a function that builds a checker board however I can't get my second conditional statement to execute and create a new line.

```js
function grid(size) {
  var board = "";
  for (i = 0; i <= (size * size); i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      board += ' ';
    } else if (i % size === 0) {
      board += "\n";
    } else {
      board += '#';
    }
  }
  console.log(board);
}
grid(8);
```

It appears the else if statement is not executing because I've tried changing the '\n' and condition to other things but nothing is printed. This question is from Eloquent Javascript and the given solution is this:

```js
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

I'm not sure why the second one works but mine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let´s analyse your code:

```
 if(i % size === 0)
```

This means, when i is equal to 0 or is a multiple of size. In your case, size is 8.

So for your if to trigger, i should be 0,8,16,32....

In all this cases, it will never fire because when i is 0,8,16,32... i % 2 is 0, so it will run the first if instead and never the second one. You should inverse the order of the ifs or run both

Comment: No. Not swap. You end up with 7 x 8 board. The else if should be a separate if at the head of the loop

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah true, running both is probably better, haven't tried it though

Answer (score 2):

`i % 2` will always execute instead of `i % (8 * 8)`. You should swap their order or remove the `else` from the second `if`.